# How and when does SQL Server occupy memory for variables?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, memory, memory-management

Let's say I have a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MY_SP  
    @LastName NVARCHAR(50),   
    @FirstName NVARCHAR(50)   
AS   
     /// my query here ///
GO
```

Then I would like to find after creating this procedure with variable

```
NVARCHAR(50)
```

How and when computer memory occupied by these variables,

When does SQL Server occupy memory, when it creates or when it executed?

How can I check how much memory is being consumed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory is allocated for parameters as part of the [execution context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-2017#execution-plan-caching-and-reuse).

> Each user that is currently executing the query has a data structure
>   that holds the data specific to their execution, such as parameter
>   values. This data structure is referred to as the execution context.
>   The execution context data structures are reused. If a user executes a
>   query and one of the structures is not being used, it is reinitialized
>   with the context for the new user.

The execution context is created when the procedure is first compiled and cached. An execution plan can have multiple execution context if required for concurrent executions as explained above. The execution context comprises a number of `8,192 byte` pages in memory.  So 81 `NVARCHAR(50)` parameters would be able to fit onto a single page.

It is not straightforward to see this but you can play around with the following to see the page count increase as you add more parameters.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE MY_SP  
@P1 nvarchar(4000) = NULL,    
@P2 nvarchar(4000) = NULL,    
@P3 nvarchar(4000) = NULL
AS 

GO

EXEC MY_SP

GO

SELECT m2.memory_object_address,
       m2.pages_in_bytes / m2.page_size_in_bytes AS pages_allocated_count,
       m2.page_size_in_bytes
FROM   sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
       JOIN sys.dm_os_memory_objects m1
         ON m1.memory_object_address = cp.memory_object_address
       JOIN sys.dm_os_memory_objects m2
         ON m1.page_allocator_address = m2.page_allocator_address
WHERE  cp.plan_handle = (SELECT ps.plan_handle
                         FROM   sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats ps
                         WHERE  ps.database_id = DB_ID()
                                AND ps.object_id = OBJECT_ID('MY_SP'))
       AND m2.type = 'MEMOBJ_EXECUTE'
```